# NAS drive details using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell. I am trying to get owner and access for a NAS drive in Windows. I tried with `get-acl` via python (using `winrm`), but its failing, saying the drive which am trying to work on is does not exist.

Example :

```
get-acl 'V:'
```

However when I try the same command for C: drive it works fine. For NAS it says:

```
Error >get-acl : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name \'V\' does not exist
```

Is there any other alternative command?

This command works fine when I login to that remote machine and execute, however gives above error when I execute through python using winrm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell command to retrieve NAS drive information](https://superuser.com/questions/1351243/powershell-command-to-retrieve-nas-drive-information)

Answer (score 1):

When you just enter V: in power shell then it tries to search for a local drive, that's the reason the program is returning the ACL in the remote machine but not the local machine. You will need to run the command using the complete location of the drive example : \server_Name\folder_name, that will return the associated groups and when you search for those groups in AD you can find who the owner is.

Comment: Thanks, however, when I try it on remote machine i get below result.
Status       Local     Remote                                            Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\itsudna001.hal.com\opcx$ 
                                                Microsoft Windows Network

suppose server name is XYZ
you mean to say search like this - get-acl '\XYZ\Y:' or '\XYZ\\\\itsudna001.hal.com\opcx$'
????

Comment: Here itsudna001 is the server name, hal.com is the domain and folder is opcx$ Microsoft Windows I would search for \\itsudna001\opcx$ Microsoft Windows .

Comment: Thanks, I tried this earlier but no luck. Same error I get